# How can it be done to replace a considerable string in which I know how it starts and ends in PYTHON?

Tags: python

Good afternoon, I have a query, I have an answer that I receive after executing an SSH connection to a server, the question is that I need to eliminate a considerable substring from the response, so I would like to know if I am successful in some method that allows the Connecting fewer lines, for example, the [replace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/) method is not effective for me, since as indicated in the image below, the replacement text is considerable.

The beginning / end of the chain that I am going to replace I know, so that would be the limits to replace

buff_string:

[image]

I must remove everything that is highlighted

```
...... code.....

shell.close() #Cerramos canal
ssh.close() #Cerramos cliente SSH
# print(val_count)
# print(buff_config.count('*B:P79COL01#'))
print(buff_string)
```

See the following link [How to remove substring from a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112171/how-to-remove-substring-from-a-string-in-python) to document me, but the reality in the response is about removing chain of short substring, the opposite of my case

Comment: ```mystring.replace('phrase', '')```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove substring from a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112171/how-to-remove-substring-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: If it appears on the internet, but how could I eliminate such a large string in an optimized way?

Comment: By what criteria do you identify the string to be removed?

Comment: that starts with the string "Authentication" and ends with the string "falta."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the substring that starts your sequence by using `index`, then use the regular list slice operator (`[<start>:<end>]`) to extract your substring:

```
data = 'foobar*B:P79COL01#barfoo'
start = '*B:P79COL01#'

print(data[data.index(start):])
-> "*B:P79COL01#barfoo"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, just what we need